# ActiveAdmin & Rails 3: How to delete user related data when deleting the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I'm working on ROR 3 app which uses ActiveAdmin.. When we delete a user from the admin module, it deletes its entry from the database.. I have other models like excel_files which belong to to users.. If I want the related entries in excel_files table also to be deleted, where can I do this with ActiveAdmin??

Comment: Could you please share the model code of 'User' or define the relations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would do this in the model, e.g.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :excel_files, dependent: :destroy

end
```

Comment: This worked :) I can now delete the result files depending on these excel files!! Thank you so much!!